# Rails ActiveAdmin Sass Import Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

This error has plagued me for more than 24 hours and I need to either solve it or drop active admin completely :

```
ArgumentError at /admin
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
(in C:/Users/joelb/RubymineProjects/bleh/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)

engine_from_pathsass-rails (4.0.2) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb
    def engine_from_path(name, dir, options)
      (this is the error line)  full_filename, syntax = Sass::Util.destructure(find_real_file(dir, name, options))
        return unless full_filename && File.readable?(full_filename)

Sprockets::SassImporter#engine_from_path
sass-rails (4.0.2) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb, line 80
Sprockets::SassImporter#find_relative
sass-rails (4.0.2) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb, line 27
Sass::Tree::ImportNode#import
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb, line 45
Sass::Tree::ImportNode#imported_file
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb, line 25
Sass::Tree::ImportNode#css_import?
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb, line 34
```

I've tried deleting the gem , rebundling , no good . From what I see activeadmin fails in the sass @import part . However the gem is included , I can see all the assets where they should be . Anyone has anything ?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this or dropping ActiveAdmin?

Also, are you using the Compass gem?

Comment: Had to drop it , built a very basic admin interface of my own and it's good enough . I'm using compass-rails...

Comment: Yea, I was getting the same error. Locking the compass-rails gem to version 2.0.0 (`gem compass-rails, '2.0.0'`) resolved this issue for me. I noticed doing so also prevented sass from updating. My guess is that the new compass-rails gem has a sass dependency that is higher than sass-rails or a mixin provided by Compass changed. If you end up testing this and it works, I'll post it as an answer. Otherwise, I'll try and figure out the root cause later.

Comment: Thanks , I'll try active admin again for my next project .. hope this helps the next person!

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/221

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by locking the sass version to 3.2.19 (gem 'sass', '>= 3.2.19' in the Gemfile).